# Cannot access .txt file with fstream

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, fstream

I'm trying to make a simple array with all the data of a `.txt` file. I'm trying to access it the way my instructor told us, but it keeps on failing, and I don't understand why. I'm not sure how to add the file on here, but I don't think that it is the actual problem.

Here's my code:

```
fstream fichierProduits("donneesProduits.txt", ios::in);

if (!fichierProduits)
{
    cout << "Impossible d'accéder au fichier" << endl;
    system("pause");
    exit(1);
}

produits tabProduits[tailleTab];

int cptProd = 0;

string ligne;   // Variable qui contiendra une ligne du fichier
string delimiteur = "##"; 

string IDp = "";
string produitp = "";
string Qtep = "";
string prixup = "";
string Catep = "";
string refp = "";
string fabp = "";

while (getline(fichierProduits, ligne))
{
    IDp = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    produitp = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    Qtep = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    prixup = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    Catep = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    refp = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    fabp = ligne.substr(0, ligne.find(delimiteur));
    ligne.erase(0, ligne.find(delimiteur) + delimiteur.length());

    // Les 7 valeurs lues seront insérés dans le tableau
    tabProduits[cptProd].ID = IDp;
    tabProduits[cptProd].produit = produitp;
    tabProduits[cptProd].Qte = Qtep;
    tabProduits[cptProd].prixu = prixup;
    tabProduits[cptProd].Cate = Catep;
    tabProduits[cptProd].ref = refp;
    tabProduits[cptProd].fab = fabp;

    cptProd++;  // Incrémenter le compteur
}

fichierProduits.close();

// Parcours du tableau pour afficher les cases non vides
cout << setiosflags(ios::left);
cout << setw(10) << "Numéro" << setw(15) << "Nom" << setw(10) << "nbH" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < cptProd; i++)
{
    cout << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].ID << setw(15) << tabProduits[i].produit << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].Qte << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].prixu << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].Cate << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].ref << setw(10) << tabProduits[i].fab << endl;
}
```

I tried to use the only other way I know how:

```
ifstream fichierProduits;
fichierProduits.open("donneesProduits.txt", ios::in);
```

But it, sadly, did not change anything.

I made sure that the file had no copies that could interfere, and made sure that the actual file was accessible for the program.

I'm also using that part in a function called from `main()` that is a `void` with `void` parameter, because I am not using anything else in that function except that code part.

Comment: I recommend keeping everything in the `produits` class.  Overload `operator>>` in the `produits` class to read in the members from a strea.

Comment: What does "It keeps failing" mean exactly? Does the file just not open? Is the output empty? Incomplete? ...? Also where does `tailleTab` come from and is it a compile time constant? If it's not, you're outside of the C++ standard which I wouldn't recommend doing, even if this code was provided by your teacher. `std::vector` would be preferrable in that case...

Comment: How would it open the file? You provided filename but you need to provide either fullpath or relative path.

Comment: My expectation is `donneesProduits.txt` is not in the current working directory when you run your code.

Comment: `fstream fichierProduits("donneesProduits.txt", ios::in);` and `ifstream fichierProduits; fichierProduits.open("donneesProduits.txt", ios::in);` are effectively identical, they do the same thing internally.